# Why would a developer include a parameter in a function that references the class it is used in?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, overriding

So I have the following situation:

```
class Child : Base, IBase
{
    Response OnOperationResponse(Base base, Parameters params)
    {
       // Code code code
    }
}

public class Base
{
    protected void OnOperationResponse(Parameters params);
}

public interface IBase
{
    Response OnOperationResponse(Base base, Parameters params);
}
```

I am leaving a lot out, but I've put in the parts that are confusing me.

So, the `Base` class and the `IBase` interface both contain the same function name, but I want to use the interface's `OnOperationResponse` call.  Where I am getting confused, is why the developer of the library added the `Base` parameter into the interface?  Shouldn't the interface realize that the function is suppose to refer to `this`?

Am I missing something here? Or is there something further under the hood that this library is hiding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the interface realize that the function is suppose to refer
>   to this?

The parameter of type `Base` being passed in `OnOperationResponse` could be *any* instance of type Base - why do you make the assumption that it should be the same as the `IBase` instance it is being called on?

A use case (totally made up admittedly) could be augmenting or modifying a `Response` similar to a decorator:

```
class Child : Base, IBase
{
    Response OnOperationResponse(Base someBase, Parameters p)
    {
        var response = someBase.OnOperationResponse(p);
        response.Foo = "bar";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that `Child` is extending `Base` - perhaps this means there's some sort of parent-child relationship going on, and `OnOperationResponse` allows you to pass in either the parent or the child?

Comment: I'm looking at examples that are like the one I have above and they access the instance with `base.Member`.  In a case like above, would `this.Member` be the same as `base.Member` in `Child.OnOperationResponse()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement IBase in Child. But, you can. Implementing just means it not only has the properties of a "Base" object, but it can also handle responses with "Base" type objects passed in. The developer may have wanted to separate these ideas, and allow you to specialize one or the other.

Either making a better handler, that implements IBase and takes Child items and handles them nicely, or by extending Base and making a grand something or another, that can still be passed back to the Child for a response.